# How to perform preprocessing for hyperspectral images

Tags: python, cnn, image-recognition

**Here I would like to apply the CNN and DNN for face recognition computing and
later will compare that both of them which one is better or faster**

My idea is -

*In the UWA hyperspectral face database, a total of 10 different faces, each face has 
3 different samples, a total of 30 face images, 7 people are selected as a training
sample, therefore a total of 21 training samples, and a total of 9 testing samples*

I am not sure how to perform preprocessing for my **hyperspetral png pictures**

Please see the Python file below and let me know how to modify

```
from keras import backend as K
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from keras.layers import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.models import load_model
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.utils import np_utils
from load_data import load_dataset, resize_image, IMAGE_SIZE
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split

import keras
import numpy as np
import os
import random
import scipy.io as sio
import spectral

class Dataset:
    def __init__(self, path_name):

        self.train_images = None
        self.train_labels = None

        self.valid_images = None
        self.valid_labels = None

        self.test_images = None            
        self.test_labels = None

        self.path_name = path_name

        self.input_shape = None

    def load(self, img_rows = IMAGE_SIZE, img_cols = IMAGE_SIZE, 
             img_channels = 3, nb_classes = 2):

        images, labels = load_dataset(self.path_name)        

        train_images, valid_images, train_labels, valid_labels = train_test_split(images, labels, test_size = 0.3, random_state = random.randint(0, 100))        
        _, test_images, _, test_labels = train_test_split(images, labels, test_size = 0.5, random_state = random.randint(0, 100))                

        if K.image_dim_ordering() == 'th':
            train_images = train_images.reshape(train_images.shape[0], img_channels, img_rows, img_cols)
            valid_images = valid_images.reshape(valid_images.shape[0], img_channels, img_rows, img_cols)
            test_images = test_images.reshape(test_images.shape[0], img_channels, img_rows, img_cols)
            self.input_shape = (img_channels, img_rows, img_cols)            

        else:

            train_images = train_images.reshape(train_images.shape[0], img_rows, img_cols, img_channels)
            valid_images = valid_images.reshape(valid_images.shape[0], img_rows, img_cols, img_channels)
            test_images = test_images.reshape(test_images.shape[0], img_rows, img_cols, img_channels)
            self.input_shape = (img_rows, img_cols, img_channels)            

            print(train_images.shape[0], 'train samples')
            print(valid_images.shape[0], 'valid samples')
            print(test_images.shape[0], 'test samples')

            train_labels = np_utils.to_categorical(train_labels, nb_classes)                        
            valid_labels = np_utils.to_categorical(valid_labels, nb_classes)            
            test_labels = np_utils.to_categorical(test_labels, nb_classes)                        

            train_images = train_images.astype('float32')            
            valid_images = valid_images.astype('float32')
            test_images = test_images.astype('float32')

            train_images /= 255
            valid_images /= 255
            test_images /= 255            

            self.train_images = train_images
            self.valid_images = valid_images
            self.test_images = test_images
            self.train_labels = train_labels
            self.valid_labels = valid_labels
            self.test_labels = test_labels

# CNN          
class Model:
    def __init__(self):
        self.model = None 

    def build_model(self, dataset, nb_classes = 2):

        self.model = Sequential() 

        self.model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, border_mode='same', input_shape = dataset.input_shape))    
        self.model.add(Activation('relu'))                                  

        self.model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3))                                                         
        self.model.add(Activation('relu'))                                  

        self.model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))                      
        self.model.add(Dropout(0.25))                                       

        self.model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, border_mode='same'))         
        self.model.add(Activation('relu'))                                  

        self.model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3))                             
        self.model.add(Activation('relu'))                                  

        self.model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))                      
        self.model.add(Dropout(0.25))                                       

        self.model.add(Flatten())                                           
        self.model.add(Dense(512))                                          
        self.model.add(Activation('relu'))                                    
        self.model.add(Dropout(0.5))                                        
        self.model.add(Dense(nb_classes))                                   
        self.model.add(Activation('softmax'))                              

        self.model.summary()

    def train(self, dataset, batch_size = 20, nb_epoch = 10, data_augmentation = True):        
        sgd = SGD(lr = 0.01, decay = 1e-6, momentum = 0.9, nesterov = True)  
        self.model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd, metrics=['accuracy'])   

        if not data_augmentation:            
            self.model.fit(dataset.train_images,
                           dataset.train_labels,
                           batch_size = batch_size,
                           nb_epoch = nb_epoch,
                           validation_data = (dataset.valid_images, dataset.valid_labels),
                           shuffle = True)

        else:            

            datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
                featurewise_center = False,             
                samplewise_center  = False,             
                featurewise_std_normalization = False,  
                samplewise_std_normalization  = False,  
                zca_whitening = False,                  
                rotation_range = 20,                    
                width_shift_range  = 0.2,              
                height_shift_range = 0.2,               
                horizontal_flip = True,                 
                vertical_flip = False)                 

            datagen.fit(dataset.train_images)                        

            self.model.fit_generator(datagen.flow(dataset.train_images, dataset.train_labels,
                                                   batch_size = batch_size),
                                     samples_per_epoch = dataset.train_images.shape[0],
                                     nb_epoch = nb_epoch,
                                     validation_data = (dataset.valid_images, dataset.valid_labels))    

    MODEL_PATH = './model.h5'
    def save_model(self, file_path = MODEL_PATH):
         self.model.save(file_path)

    def load_model(self, file_path = MODEL_PATH):
         self.model = load_model(file_path)

    def evaluate(self, dataset):
         score = self.model.evaluate(dataset.test_images, dataset.test_labels, verbose = 1)
         print("%s: %.2f%%" % (self.model.metrics_names[1], score[1] * 100))

    def face_predict(self, image):    

        if K.image_dim_ordering() == 'th' and image.shape != (1, 3, IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE):
            image = resize_image(image)                             
            image = image.reshape((1, 3, IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE))       
        elif K.image_dim_ordering() == 'tf' and image.shape != (1, IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, 3):
            image = resize_image(image)
            image = image.reshape((1, IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, 3))                    

        image = image.astype('float32')
        image /= 255

        result = self.model.predict_proba(image)
        print('result:', result)

        result = self.model.predict_classes(image)        

        return result[0]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dataset = Dataset('./data/')    
    dataset.load()

    model = Model()
    model.build_model(dataset)

    model.build_model(dataset)

    model.train(dataset)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dataset = Dataset('./data/')    
    dataset.load()

    model = Model()
    model.build_model(dataset)
    model.train(dataset)
    model.save_model(file_path = './model.h5')

if __name__ == '__main__':    
    dataset = Dataset('./data/')    
    dataset.load()

    model = Model()
    model.load_model(file_path = './model.h5')
    model.evaluate(dataset)
```

Reference ---

https://sites.google.com/site/zohaibnet/Home/databases      (download HSFD)

http://www.mecs-press.org/ijem/ijem-v8-n1/IJEM-V8-N1-6.pdf

https://github.com/gokriznastic/HybridSN/blob/master/Hybrid-Spectral-Net.ipynb

Comment: I have uploaded a tool for hyperspectral image augmentation to [Github](https://github.com/mabdelhack/hyperspectral_image_generator)

Answer (score 1):

define a function, which takes input an image and output preprocessed image. In the function you can define what preprocessing you want to do.

let's call the function as `preproc`

then in your data generator you can use it as:

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
                featurewise_center = False,             
                samplewise_center  = False,             
                featurewise_std_normalization = False,  
                samplewise_std_normalization  = False,  
                zca_whitening = False,                  
                rotation_range = 20,                    
                width_shift_range  = 0.2,              
                height_shift_range = 0.2,               
                horizontal_flip = True,                 
                vertical_flip = False,
                preprocessing_function = preproc)
```

Please note: function will be applied on each input. The function will run after the image is resized and augmented.